# Multiple Versions of Wordpress on Same Webserver

Tags: wordpress

I have a web server running Wordpress 3.3 for a couple of sites and that is fine. I want to put another new website on this webserver but figure I should use the newer Wordpress 3.6 for this one. When uploading the newer version of Wordpress to my webserver my FTP client tells me that some of the Wordpress files already exist in the destination (only a handful). The thing is, I am uploading to a new blank folder. There are no Wordpress files in there.

I am wondering if there is some kind of conflict going on with 3.3 vs. 3.6 on my webserver?

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that either you don't know what you are doing or you FTP client is cheating on you :).

If you have a separate directory for each web site (running wordpress or not) together with separate databases for each website then you can run multiple websites using different wordpress versions without any problems.

The only problems you can encounter is that you would need to upgrade you php and/or mysql or other libraries on your LAMP server for new wordpress software to be run, thats normally back-compatible and shouldn't affect your older wordpress installations but its always good to check before an upgrade.